# How to call a function from hash in perl

Tags: perl

i trying yo doing the the following pseudocode in perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#App.pm

use strict;
use OtherModule;
use Other2Module;

sub App::hashF
{
  my $hash_funtion = {
    'login' => OtherModule::login,
    'logout' => Other2Module::logout
  };

  my($module, $params) = @_;

  return $hash->{$module}($params);
}
```

but i get error like:
-  Can't use string ("login") as a subroutine ref while "strict refs"
-  Can't use bareword ("OtherModelo") as a HASH ref while "strict refs"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I decided to enhance your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#App.pm

use strict; use warnings;

package App;

use OtherModule;
use Other2Module;

my $hash = {
  login  => \&OtherModule::login,
  logout => \&Other2Module::logout,
};

sub hashF
{    
  my($module, @params) = @_;

  return $hash->{$module}->(@params);
}
```

We cannot assign bare names, but we can pass around *code references*. The `&` Sigil denotes the "code" type or a subroutine, and `\` gives us a reference to it. (Not getting a reference would execute the code; not something we want. Never execute `&subroutine` unprovoked.)

BTW: Hashes can only hold scalar values, and (code) references are a kind of scalar.

When we want to call our sub from the hash, we have to use the *dereference operator* `->`.
`$hash->{$module}` returns a code reference as value; `->(@arglist)` executes it with the given arguments.

Another BTW: Don't write `App::hashF` unless you are working inside an external module. You can declare your current namespace by writing `package App` or whatever name you like (should correspond with path/name of .pm file).

Comment: thanks i have only 2 hour with perl but i need a simple system with routing :)

Answer (score 3):

This construct:

```
my $hash_funtion = {
  'login' => OtherModule::login,
  'logout' => Other2Module::logout
};
```

is calling the `OtherModule::login` function and assigning its return value to `$hash_funtion->{login}`, similarly for `logout`. You want to store references to the functions in the hash's values:

```
my $hash_funtion = {
  'login'  => \&OtherModule::login,
  'logout' => \&Other2Module::logout
};
```

Then the rest will work fine (assuming you correct the typos of course).

Comment: pedantically, you are describing what `{ 'login' => scalar(OtherModule::login), 'logout' => scalar(Other2Module::logout) }` does; if login/logout return 0 or 2+ elements, things are much worse